# Automatically Collapsing the 1 cell, when i clicked on 2 cell, in table View

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

i have written code for Expanding and collapse , here my problem is , In a table View , when i clicked on 1st cell, it is expanding correctly, but when i am clicking on 2nd cell , automatically 1st cell is collapsing.
my code is

```html
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(isFilter)
    {
        return [searchArray count];
    }
    else
        return  [responceArray count];
}




-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Content1"];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Content1"];
        
    }
    
        UILabel *namelab = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *state = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        UILabel *status = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
        UILabel *serialNo=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
        UILabel *company = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        UIView *aview=(UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    if(isFilter)
    {
        
        serialNo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"job_id"]];
         namelab.text=[[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"maintenance_friendly_name"];
        state.text=[[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"site_id"];
        status.text=[[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"maintenance_status"];
        company.text=[[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"orgname"];
    }
    else
    {
        serialNo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[responceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"job_id"]];
        namelab.text=[[responceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"maintenance_friendly_name"];
        state.text=[[responceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"site_id"];
        status.text=[[responceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"maintenance_status"];
        company.text=[[responceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"orgname"];
    
}
    //alternative background colors for better division ;)
    
    if (indexPath.row %2 ==1)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.9 blue:.9 alpha:1];
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.8 green:.8 blue:.8 alpha:1];
    
    // name.text = [cellTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    if (isTagsExapanded == YES && isSelectedRowIndex == indexPath.row) {
        
        
        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,160);
        
        aview.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        
        [cell.contentView viewWithTag:3].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        
    }else{
        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,160);
        aview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];

    }
    
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    if (isTagsExapanded && isSelectedRowIndex == indexPath.row) {
        
        return 160;
        
    }else{
        
        return  75;
        
    }
    return 0;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    
    if (!isTagsExapanded ) {
        
        isTagsExapanded = YES;
        isSelectedRowIndex = indexPath.row;
        
    }else{
        
        isTagsExapanded = NO;
        
    }
    [_collapeExpandUITBV reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Please explain properly what is the issue here, whether you require 1st cell to collapse on 2nd selection or not

Comment: when i m clicking on the 1st cell,  it is expanding perfectly, but when i am clicking on 2nd cell, 1st cell is automatically collapsed,  but i want  1st cell also to be expanded , until i clicked on the 1st cell , it should not be collapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st cell is getting disabled because of `isSelectedRowIndex` property. At a time this will hold only one index hence only one cell will get displayed as expanded, and rest others will get collapsed as per your code.

For your requirement, it will require to maintain an array of selected cell indexes. Here is the code which might help you out.

In ViewController.h file (Or in ViewController.m file in category definition)

```
NSMutableArray *selectedCellIndexes;
```

In ViewController.m file:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   if (selectedCellIndexes == nil) {
      selectedCellIndexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }

   if(![selectedCellIndexes containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [selectedCellIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];  // add if it does not exist
    }
    else
    {
        [selectedCellIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];  // remove if it exists
    }
    [tableView reloadData];  // redraw all cell again
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Cell alloc - init data here
   ...
   ...

   if(selectedCellIndexes && [selectedCellIndexes containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])    
   {
      // expanded cell code here
   }
   else {
      // collapsed cell code here
   }
   return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
   int rowHeight = 0;
   if(selectedCellIndexes && [selectedCellIndexes containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]]) 
        rowHeight = EXPANDED_CELL_HEIGHT; // define this value as constants 
   }
   else 
   {     
      rowHeight = COLLAPSED_CELL_HEIGHT; // define this value as constants 
   }
   return rowHeight;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that this property is a single cell attribute or the entire table attribute.

Comment: isTagsExapanded

Comment: for both row and section

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `isTagsExapanded` and `isSelectedRowIndex` property seems to be common or singleton for whole class so if you select any row once then `if` portion will be execute and your `isTagsExapanded` set to `YES` and when your table reload it will expand according to your datasource and delegate methods now when you second time select any cell then `isTagsExapanded` is set to `NO` and reload table sets tableview with no row expanded.

So whenever use tap cell and you are setting `isSelectedRowIndex` and reloading table that mean `cellforrow` set cell expanded only at `isSelectedRowIndex` and all other cell got set to collapsing state because of `if (isTagsExapanded == YES && isSelectedRowIndex == indexPath.row)` this condition. when `isSelectedRowIndex == indexPath.row` become true at that time only your cell will expand.

So, if you want to keep your expanded cell expanded then you should manage array of `indexPath` for your expanded cell. And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightforrow set` `expanded frame and 160  height` for every indexpath of that array (array of selected indexpaths or selected row or expanded cells).

you can get array of indexpath something like,

```
   NSArray *arr = [yourTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```